Errors adding AdWords gtag.js to default_head_blocks.xml in Magento 2.4.7
I am trying to add a gtag.js script to httpdocs/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
I understand I should be overriding this file in my custom theme, and I will once I get it working.
The default_head_blocks.xml file is now as below:

The error message I get is.
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Theme layout update file '/var/www/vhosts/iplus2.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml' is not valid.
Specification mandates value for attribute async
Line: 16
attributes construct error
Line: 16
Couldn't find end of Start Tag script line 16
Line: 16
Opening and ending tag mismatch: head line 9 and script
Line: 16
Opening and ending tag mismatch: page line 8 and head
Line: 19
Extra content at the end of the document
Line: 20
Looks like some kind of syntax error, but I don't understand why.
Can anyone help please, this has been driving me crazy for 2 days now!
Thanks Jim

Adobe Commerce does not support adding scripts directly into XML files like default_head_blocks.xml.
Instead, you can include scripts using alternative methods.
One option is to add the script through the Admin Head Section in the theme configuration, which is ideal for scripts required globally across the website.
Another approach is to include the script in a .phtml file, such as header.phtml, which is better suited for scripts specific to certain pages or blocks.
Alternatively, you can create a custom JavaScript file and reference it in the XML, offering modularity and reusability.

Thank you. I think the custom javascript file , referenced from the layout.xml is the best way to go.

@JimEdgar Please do not edit the answer to add a follow-on question. If the answer doesn't work, edit your question. If you got your answer but have a new question, ask a new question.
